# Concat three or more fields in doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Doctrine query builder allows me to concat two fields only.

```
class Expr {
// ...
public function concat($x, $y); // Returns Expr\Func
```

To concatenate 3 fields I use:

```
$qb->expr()->concat(
    'table.field1',
    $qb->expr()->concat('table.field2', 'table.field3')
);
```

And the SQL will be:

```
CONCAT('table.field1', CONCAT('table.field2', 'table.field3'))
```

How to get **one** concat?

When I try to call directly

```
new Expr\Func('CONCAT', array('table.field1', 'table.field2', 'table.field3'));
```

Executing query gives me an error

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 237: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS, got ','

Dumping DQL:

```
CONCAT('table.field1', 'table.field2', 'table.field3')
```

Dumping SQL using *$qb->getQuery()->getSQL()*:

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 237: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS, got ','

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14945317/how-do-i-use-concat-ws-together-with-in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CONCAT` with variable number of arguments has been introduced in [Doctrine ORM version 2.4.0](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/commit/4841a068be7a26f9d9f6366563eead19a7fffd40), so you are probably using an older version. I've tested a similar DQL in my project and works as expected.

You should upgrade your Doctrine ORM deps with:

```
php composer.phar require doctrine/orm:~2.4
```

Note that (for now) variable arguments are supported only by `Expr\Func` constructor, but is not supported in `Expr::concat` method; you still need this syntax:

```
new Expr\Func('CONCAT', array('table.field1', 'table.field2', 'table.field3'));
```

**UPDATE** I've created a [PR on GitHub](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/pull/1397) to support multiple arguments in `Expr::concat`